# How to split this Python String to get meaningful output?

Tags: python

I have this String:

```
"ParsedText": "180 Grade IV\r\n\Class VIII Pass\r\nwww.forbes.com, Since 2012\r\n"
```

I am trying to remove all `\r\n` and get everyword inside a `list`. This is what I meant:

```
["180 Grade IV", "Class VIII Pass", "www.forbes.com", "Since 2012"]
```

How can this be achieved? Please provide your valuable ideas. Thanks

Comment: `.split('\r\n')`?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `.split('\\r\\n')`

Answer (score 1):

try this

**code**

```py
string="180 Grade IV\r\nClass VIII Pass\r\nwww.forbes.com, Since 2012\r\n"
print(string.split('\r\n'))
```

**output**

```
['180 Grade IV', '\\Class VIII Pass', 'www.forbes.com, Since 2012', '']
```

did you mean like this??